# Alternate proof of the commutative property of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I want to prove $u + v = v + u$, where $u$ and $v$ are vectors. I've seen the proof where you apply the vector rule for addition but I was wondering if this proof also works.

$$u + v = v + u $$

$$0 = (v + u) - (u + v)$$

$$0 = (v_1 - v_1 + ... + v_n - v_n) + (u_1 - u_1 + ... + u_n - u_n)$$
$$ 0 = 0$$
therefore the property is proven.

Comment: It could be helpful what you mean by "vector rule for addition"

Comment: Also your proof is not correct because between line 2 and 3, you use the commutative property to prove the commutative property! By claiming $(v+u)-(u+v)=(v-v)+(u-u)$

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition